# Field Guide meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, metaphors

There is a book by George Lakoff named "More than Cool Reason: A Field Guide to Poetic Metaphor"

I wonder what "Field Guide" means here. In Wikipedia it is mentioned that:

> A field guide is a book designed to help the reader identify wildlife
>   or other objects of natural occurrence. It is generally designed to be
>   brought into the 'field' or local area where such objects exist to
>   help distinguish between similar objects.

But here this meaning doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you understand that *[The Macintosh Bible](https://archive.org/details/mac_The_Macintosh_Bible_8th_edition_2002)* is not actually a Bible?

Comment: It’s a metaphor!

Answer (score 1):

The format of a field guide and its entries is likely to be what they're getting at, as well as it being small enough to be taken with you, but more in-depth an a pocket guide.

With little or no general material (that mostly consisting of entries about common features of related species) they contain an entry per species. Each entry is of the same format, typically consisting of one or more illustrations, some data such as size, when they're present, etc., and a description of the creature. The description is more free-form but still set out in a fairly predictable way. The idea is that once you're familiar with a guide, parsing an unfamiliar entry is quick.

Such a guide should be complete, for some value of complete (it may cover all *common* species in a given region, for example).

I have seen "field guide" used as a metaphor in relation to books about other things, though I struggle to see how it would apply in this case. At the very least each entry should start with some basic data and an example, before a couple of paragraphs of more descriptive text.